# Ruby group_by values as resource collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have `Record` model.

**record.rb**

```
scope :some_record_scope ...
```

I can use this scope on model `Record.some_record_scope`

But i need grouped this model by hour (for example). And after use each value with some scopes as Record`s collection.
My code:

```
records = Record.all.order(:created_at)
grouped_records = records.group_by{ |r| r.created_at.strftime('%H') }

grouped_records.each do |interval, collection|
  collection.some_record_scope
  ...
end
```

But i see error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `some_record_scope' for #<Array:0x007fbb4d104b30>
```

How i can use it as collection?

Comment: It is already a collection (an array, to be more precise.) `some_record_scope` is the reason of an error and nobody here has any clue what is stands for.

Comment: can you share your log file.And what is `some_record_scope`?

Comment: You cannot call a method on a collection or array.Rather it should be a instance method or class method.

Comment: Can you give us a better idea what your end goal is? I think there is probably a better way to group your records, such as an SQL group function. But without knowing what your data looks like, and what you are trying to get, I can't make any recommendations.

Answer (score 0):

```
Record.some_record_scope.order(:created_at).group_by {|r| r.created_at.strftime('%H') }
```

Comment: Add some explanation to your answer please.

Comment: yes, I implemented so, but what does if you need more one scope?

Answer (score 0):

To add more information and explanation to the above answer, the reason your getting the error is because you have called .all and .group_by before calling the scope, the previous answers:

```
Record.some_record_scope.order(:created_at).group_by {|r| r.created_at.strftime('%H') }
```

works because some_record_scope is being called on the ActiveRelation object as it should be, 
and in terms of multiple scopes, I think you can just chain the scope references like `Record.some_scope.another_scope.order......`

Comment: to be more clear, .all returns an Array, not an ActiveRelation object containing an array, you need to call scopes on the ActiveRelation, Array class has no knowledge of your self defined scopes